# How to Include single quote in the STUFF

Tags: sql-server

I have my sql query as follows which is giving the result by Capitalizing the given strings but I need the with single quote on each of the individual one how can I do that

```
DECLARE @Xml XML 
DECLARE @Propercase VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(5) 

SET @delimiter=' ' 


DECLARE @string nvarchar(max)='ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL'
SET @Xml = Cast(( '<String>' 
                  + @string+ '</String>' ) AS XML)

;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT a.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS strings 
         FROM   @Xml.nodes('String') AS FN(a))

-- SELECT * FROM cte;

SELECT @ProperCase = Stuff((SELECT ' ' +'('+ + Upper(LEFT(strings, 1)) 
                                   + Upper(Substring(strings, 2, Len(strings)) + ')'
                                   ) 
                            FROM   cte 
                            FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')    

                            SELECT @ProperCase
```

Currently my output is as follows `(ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL)` I need this to be `('ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Xml XML 
DECLARE @Propercase VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(5) 

SET @delimiter=' ' 


DECLARE @string nvarchar(max)='ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL'
SET @Xml = Cast(( '<String>' 
                  + @string+ '</String>' ) AS XML)

;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT a.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS strings 
         FROM   @Xml.nodes('String') AS FN(a))
SELECT @ProperCase = '(' + REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT ','''+ Upper(LEFT(strings, 1)) 
                                   + Upper(Substring(strings, 2, Len(strings))) + ''')'                                   
                            FROM   cte 
                            FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),',',''',''')    

SELECT @ProperCase
```

Note that all the STUFF really does is drop the leading comma

Answer (score 0):

Double up the single quotes to be output as one single quote character while still being wrapped in single quotes. So four (4) single quotes will output a single quote as a String.

```sql
DECLARE @prelimiter VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(5)

SET @prelimiter = '''' --## Ouptuts single quote
SET @delimiter = ''', ''' --## Ouptuts single quote then comma then space then single quote

SELECT
STUFF(' ', 1, 1,
  '(' + @prelimiter  + 'ABC' + @delimiter + 'DEF' + @delimiter +  'GHI' + ''')'
) AS Example
```

Output: `('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')`